# Alt+Printscreen stopped working, how to find processes listening to events

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, events

Very odd issue today. I was going to post a thread about another issue and wanted to take a screenshot of a terminal window. I got it all prepped, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Printscreen</kbd> and nothing happened.

I went into Keyboard Shortcuts to see if redefining the shortcut worked. It did. I tried to set it back to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Printscreen</kbd> but the window just sat there listening for a keypress. It's as if I never pushed a key.

Both the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Printscreen</kbd> keys work independently just fine... I've also tried looking at the output of `xev` as I press the keys. It hears the Alt press but doesn't hear the Printscreen afterwards.

I've tried this from both within Compiz and plain metacity. I also have a spare keyboard and that shows identical behaviour (one keyboard is PS/2, the spare is USB - so not a port issue).

It's like there's something sitting in the event chain spitting on the event so that nothing else can hear it. My question is basically: how can you find the processes responding to certain events?

As requested:

```
oli@bert:~$ xmodmap -pke | grep -i mode
keycode  82 = KP_Subtract XF86_Prev_VMode KP_Subtract XF86_Prev_VMode
keycode  86 = KP_Add XF86_Next_VMode KP_Add XF86_Next_VMode
keycode 100 = Henkan_Mode NoSymbol Henkan_Mode
keycode 203 = Mode_switch NoSymbol Mode_switch
```

And

```
oli@bert:~$ xmodmap -pke | grep -i print
keycode 107 = Print Sys_Req Print Sys_Req
keycode 218 = Print NoSymbol Print
```

**Edit:** When I posted this I was on Lucid with a home-built 2.6.35 kernel. It turns out my issue is related to the kernel and not X.

Somebody somewhere has decided that alt-printscreen should render a SysRq event. Technically speaking, perhaps it should but this breaks what-must-be over a decade of Linux and Windows "known behaviour".

Comment: I had a similar issue where I wasn't able to use two key sequences on my keyboard. The first was solved by looking at my Keyboard Layout Options and finding that that key was being used to do something like change the keyboard layout. The other was fixed when I found that two of the three keys in the key sequence were a shortcut in themselves.

Comment: Do you have any other programs running that would be intercepting the `alt` key?

Comment: I didn't have an issue with this on my laptop running `10.04` - What version are you running?

Comment: @Marco: `10.04`. I don't believe it's a bug so much as it's something else interfering with the event stack. @tj111: Not that I know of but that's part of the problem. I'd like to know what's listening to global keyboard events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per my edit, this appears to be directly linked to the kernel version 2.6.35 (and probably subsequent kernels) whereby alt+prscr renders a sysrq event.

SysRq appears to be unbindable (at least from my messing around) but you can disable the silly new behaviour by adding the following to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
kernel.sysrq = 0
```

Comment: SysRq is unbindable because that's why it was [created](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SysRq): "Introduced by IBM with the PC/AT, it was intended to be available as a special key to directly invoke low-level operating system functions with no possibility of conflicting with any existing software."

Comment: @Roger: Perhaps that's the case but for as long as I've been using Linux, the kernel has let it trickle through to be bindable as alt+printscreen. Stopping that behaviour after such a long time is a bug in itself.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, just explaining why sysrq works the way it does.  You might try winkey/super bindings; I use it for almost all of my window manager shortcuts.

Comment: This is weird: I had the same issue, but before changing anything I tried to see what my current setting was: `sudo sysctl -a | kernel.sysrq` shows... `kernel.sysrq=0` !!! But the fix was still needed: `sudo sysctl -w kernel.sysrq=0` and the problem was gone! Pretty confusing, huh?

Comment: Mmm... I'm sure that right now the Alt + PrtSc works as intended. The only way to activate sysrq is using Ctrl + Alt + Shift.

Answer (score 1):

Since you indicate PrintScreen works but alt+printscreen doesn't, it could be something to do with your modifier mapping.

If you have 2 Alt keys, can you try with both and see if behaviour is same ?

Also, can u run the command `xmodmap -pke | grep -i mode` in a terminal and check if that indicates one of the alt keys is mapped as "Mode switch" key ? Typically you would see 1 or more keysym lines containing codes assigned to the Mode switch key.

Also run `xmodmap -pke | grep -i print` in a terminal and see if the codes printed to the right of the equal sign match with the below line.

```
keycode 107 = Print Sys_Req Print Sys_Req
```

See [this page](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/xmodmap.1x.php) for explanation of the syntax of the keysym line.

Comment: Edited my post. Looks like these mappings are present and correct. AltGr is not the same as Alt. AFAIK AltGr+PrtSc shouldn't show a printscreen window but if it should, it's not here.

Comment: You're right. Mod maps look fine. Strange as it sounds, someone is eating `Alt+Prnt Scrn` ...

Answer (score 1):

Reported bug is there.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/metacity/+bug/642792

Comment: +1 for filling such a detailed report (including the correct kernel workaround)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just using Print Screen?  I've never heard of using Alt with it.

Comment: `Alt + PrintScreen` grabs current window.

Comment: Yes, the key works fine. Normal printscreen window pops up. Alt+PS should take the windowshot but doesn't.

Comment: `Alt + PrintScreen` exists since the dawn of time, maco ;) I remember using it in Windows 98