# How can I print-screen just one window and not my entire desktop?

Tags: printing, window, screenshot, print-screen

I could swear I've always been able to do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> to get 'just that window' but right now I am getting my entire desktop.

Any idea why this would be or what I can do to get my ability to do small window screen shots?

I've tried a lot of combination with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> keys, but no luck, nothing happens in response.  One option: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> lets me do a selection using a cross hair to size out the screen capture but I don't know where this gets saved.  I'm not being given the choice and it's not in Desktop or Pictures.

I use an external keyboard, but I've tried using the laptop's own keyboard and no difference.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and the laptop is a Samsung Ultrabook 900

Update:  I rebooted and it "fixed" it - for now.  However this is not the first time I've seen this so I'm still curious as to why it happens, what I can do to fix w/o reboot and if other share the same problem.

**2014 Update:**

- <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> - print desktop
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Print Screen</kbd> - print window
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Print Screen</kbd> - select and print area

all seem to be working fine now.

Comment: what currently happens when you hit those key-combos?

Comment: You can try `gnome-screenshot -w -d 4`. Will take snapshot of window.

Comment: I tried that at the command line and it locked up my machine and I had to reboot.

Comment: Have you tried Shift+Prt sc?

Comment: @Seth, I don't know about your machine, but on mine Shift+PrtSc does the area-select screenshot, just like Shift+Ctrl+PrtSc.

Comment: there's also `gnome-screenshot -i` for an interactive window

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm not sure if Ubuntu 12 has a similar settings tools. Pull up **System Settings** and look at your **Keyboard** settings. Shortcuts contain many keys that your system may be expect you to use. Make sure you don't have a conflict with another keyboard shortcut and check that your screenshot shortcut is what you are expecting to use. I've disabled the general **ALT** key for dashboard that might interfere.

This is what it looks like in Ubuntu 13:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

I don't have a fix for this issue, but I could suggest another option: use [Shutter [image: Install shutter]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shutter).
It's a pretty advanced screenshot application that lets you do a lot more than just take screenshots - including choosing where to save them.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

you dont need to use any tool **ubuntu 18.04** supports this out of the box simply use these keybinding

1. Specifc Window in focus <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Prnt Scrn</kbd>
2. Full Screen <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>prt sc</kbd>

if the funtion key is not available/doesn't work out,

1. go to settings
2. Under keyboard
3. search for screenshot and tap on each action and set the desired keybindings for a desired action,hope this helps

[image]

Comment: Another answer already says `Alt` + `Fn` + `Print Screen` combination. However neither that answer nor your own points out the `Fn` key doesn't exist on traditional keyboards. The `Fn` key is usually only found on laptops and special keyboards with backlit keys or other special hardware functions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I have updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

My 'answer' to this, at least for now was to look for the app itself.  So I went to dash home (top left icon with circle) and looked for the 'Screenshot' app then when I saw it I dragged it to my unity icons on the left and now it's simply available as an app and I get the options of capturing just the window, etc. when I use it.

[image]

Comment: Just a note: You can also press Shift+PrtSc to be able to select a specific part of the screen. Simply press it, then drag a rectangle over the area you want to screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Prnt Scrn</kbd> = Only print the window

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is that on many (most?) keyboards the PrtScn key is also the SysRq key, and Alt+SysRq is the "Magic SysRq Key" (see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/5168/50450).  You can either disable the Magic SysRq key, or change the screenshot window shortcut to something else.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Prnt Scrn</kbd> and **release the buttons**, will print-screen only the active window.

Answer (score -1):

## Try this! [ Ubuntu 20.04.4 by Terminal ]

# Screenshot a specific window, in this case a Firefox window:

```
import -window "$(wmctrl -l | cut -d ' ' -f 5- | grep -i firefox)" ~/Pictures/result.jpg
```

# Explaining the "**wmctrl -l | cut -d ' ' -f 5- | grep -i firefox**", list open windows and cut out the window name part by filtering on a keyword. Install the packages if necessary!

**Edit:**

Make sure you have a Firefox window open before testing!