# Print Screen captures two Spaces not one

Tags: print-screen

When I press the "Print Screen" the output captures both desktops instead of one!

This problem existed since I updated to Ubuntu 13.10.[image]

Update: I opened "Displays" from "System Settings", and found "Built-in Display" and "Unknown Display".

Comment: Can you show a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have the screenshot of one display, the "Unknown Display" should be turned off from the Display window which can be found in "System Settings".

Answer (score 12):

When you have multiple screens connected, I assume that `print-screen` usually captures both monitors at the same. It happens to me even now though I'm on a 12.04 (LTS).

You have number of options to over come this but of course not just limited to **Print screen**.

- You may use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>Print screen</kbd> (this will only capture the current active window but not the entire screens itself)
- You may also use **Screenshot** app from dash menu, hit super (WIN) key & select **Grab the current window** (will take the last active window) or **Select area to grab** (required area can be selected) else the other options as required
- Use [Shutter [image: Install shutter]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shutter), pretty advanced screenshot application that lets you do a lot more than just take screenshots - including choosing where to save them

**Source:** [How can I print-screen just one window and not my entire desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/a/220236/179042)

Comment: I have only one physical screen. I am using ubuntu on a laptop. What is being captured is to desktops. Sorry for the misleading title.

Comment: I'm still not clear with your question yet. Could you please edit your question and add more details explaining a little more with screen shot if possible.

Comment: I have added a picture, this is the ouput of the Print Screen key.

Comment: As your comment says that you've one physical screen but your image  does seems that you've dual monitors connected (just an assumption). Pretty much confusing.

Comment: I have opened "Displays" from "System Settings". I found two displays, Built-in Display and Unknown Display!